# pass bash variable to awk in order to extract characters at certain positions

Tags: bash, awk, character, extract

I am extracting characters from string at certain positions with this command:

```
left=1; right=4; grep ETM21CH01EPU3Z -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk '{print substr($0,1,4)}'
```

and getting this correct output:

```
GTTG
```

Now I would like to replace **1** and **4** by values in bash variables **left** and **right**.

I tried this:

```
left=1; right=4; grep ETM21CH01EPU3Z -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk -v l=$left r=$right '{print substr($0,l,r)}'
```

awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{print substr($0,l,r)}' for reading

Any suggestions, please? Thanks.

EDIT: copied from comment below so we can actually read it:

Well, I also have a file, where is written what to search (for example ETM21CH01EPU3Z) and at which positions. So the whole code is:

```
while read -r line; do
   echo $line;
   name=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 1`;
   left=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2`;
   right=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 3`;
   grep $name -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk -v l=$left -v r=$right '{print substr($0,l,r)}';
done < CL6o_blastoutput_SLf_454.fna_out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `-v` before your `right` variable. Every variable that you want to pass into `awk` must be preceded by a `-v`.

Change it to:

```
awk -v l=$left -v r=$right '{print substr($0,l,r)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

@dogbane gave you the specific answer you asked for BUT you don't need that long chain of commands and pipes just to print the first 4 characters of the line after you find some pattern. Try this instead:

```
left=1; right=4; awk -v l="$left" -v r="$right" 'f{print substr($0,l,r);f=0} /ETM21CH01EPU3Z/{f=1}' SLf_454.fna
```

Obviously you don't need left and right shell variables either if this is all you're using them for:

```
awk -v l="1" -v r="4" 'f{print substr($0,l,r);f=0} /ETM21CH01EPU3Z/{f=1}' SLf_454.fna
```

EDIT: I copied your command into your original question so we could read your script.

Try this (untested):

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR { left[$1]=$2; right[$1]=$3; next }
{
   for (name in found) {
      print substr($0,left[name],right[name])
      delete found[name]
   }
   for (name in left) {
      if ($0 ~ name) {
         found[name]
      }
   }
}
' CL6o_blastoutput_SLf_454.fna_out SLf_454.fna
```

Comment: Well, I also have a file, where is written what to search (for example ETM21CH01EPU3Z) and at which positions. So the whole code is: while read -r line; do echo $line; name=\`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 1\`; left=\`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2`; right=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 3\`; grep $name -A1 SLf_454.fna | tail -n 1 | awk -v l=$left -v r=$right '{print substr($0,l,r)}'; done<CL6o_blastoutput_SLf_454.fna_out Thanks!